# Проблема с точностью

Tags: delphi, double

Есть строка, которая выдает число с плавающей точкой, представленное на картинке (выделенная строка):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я рассчитывал, что эта строка, будет выдавать только целочисленные цифры (во всяком случае 2 месяца – ошибок не было), и вот появилась проблема.
Хотя я в дебагере разложил эту строку на отдельные составляющие, и как бы «*Pu_Capacity*» = 1000, должна была убрать точку…
Я пробовал, просто написать «FloatToStr(40)», результат 40.

Вопрос:
Как избавиться от это напасти… Функция должна как всегда выдавать целочисленное значение.

Comment: Эм, это не форум

Comment: Используй integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Округляйте. Как именно округлять - зависит от вашей задачи.
Округляйте, присваивайте целому и выводите уже его - гарантированно будете иметь целое значение :)

Ну, или переводите в строку с соответствующей точностью - округлением до целого.

В общем случае числа с плавающей точкой вам ничего не гарантируют.

Comment: **Harry**, да спасибо, наверно действительно лучше "*Round*" до целого, и вперед. Насколько это было правильно, покажет только время

Comment: Кстати, судя по всему у вас там расчёты с деньгами идут (edPrice?). Для таких расчётов типы с плавающей запятой - не лучший вариант, из-за погрешностей и неточного представления десятичных дробей. Я бы Вам посоветовал почитать про тип Currency и вообще погуглить на тему как делаются денежные расчёты в приложениях.